# Terraform 0.11: conditional vpc_config in aws_lambda_function

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.11

I am trying to deploy a Lambda function with a conditional on the `vpc_config` block. I have tried using count inside `vpc_config` but it is not possible to use a count statement there. Per the documentation for the resource, if you pass in empty lists as follows, the `vpc_config` portion is ignored:

```
  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids = []
    security_group_ids = []
  }
```

I can confirm that this does work as expected (no VPC configuration is attempted).

I have therefore tried using conditionals for `subnet_ids` and `security_group_ids` - something along the lines of `var.vpc_function ? var.subnet_ids : []` - but you cannot pass in a list in a conditional statement. The closest I have got to a solution is the below hacky number, which joins then splits the lists:

```
  resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_function" {
  ...
  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids = ["${split(",", var.vpc_function ? join(",", var.subnet_ids) : join(",", var.empty_array))}"]
    security_group_ids = ["${split(",", var.vpc_function ? join(",", aws_security_group.lambda_security_group.*.id) : join(",", var.empty_array))}"]
  }

variable "vpc_function" {
  default = "false"
}
variable "subnet_ids" {
  type = "list"
  default = ["subnet-a", "subnet-b"]
}
variable "empty_array" {
  type = "list"
  default = []
}
```

This applies fine the first time both where `vpc_function` is true or false, which is great, but where `vpc_function` is false, terraform always sees the above as a change on each reapply:

```
  vpc_config.#:                      "0" => "1"
  vpc_config.0.security_group_ids.#: "0" => "1"
  vpc_config.0.security_group_ids.0: "" => ""
  vpc_config.0.subnet_ids.#:         "0" => "1"
  vpc_config.0.subnet_ids.0:         "" => ""
```

I guess the problem is that my joined-then-split list is not seen as [], but rather as a list with some (blank) content.

Does anyone else have a solution for this? I have tried to use Terraform 0.12 as well but couldn't figure it out. Maybe someone has done something similar in Terraform 0.12 and could lend some pointers?

Comment: I believe this is the best you can do with the limitations of Terraform 0.11. You have tried the method that people normally attempt for this situation/use case.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up finding the solution in terraform 12 in the end:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_function" {
...
  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids = var.vpc_function ? var.subnet_ids : []
    security_group_ids = var.vpc_function ? aws_security_group.lambda_security_group.*.id : []
  }
...
}
```

Variable subnet_ids is passed in as follows:

```
subnet_ids = ["subnet-123", "subnet-345", "subnet-456"]
```

And aws_security_group.lambda_security_group.*.id is created as a normal resource.

Comment: Couldn't you just provide default value for these vars (making default value be []) and avoid the tertiary statements?